# Hibernate/JPA Directionless Self-Reference

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Say I have `Person` and `Friendship` JPA entities. A `Friendship` is between two people and contains information like when they met, the type of their relationship, etc.

**From a `Person` instance, I would like to access all `Friendships` involving that person**. The confusing part is that a friendship is what i'm calling "directionless" relationship (not sure the proper word). A friendship between person 1 and person 2 is the same as a friendship between person 2 and person 1. Do I need to have two separate `@OneToMany` relationships in `Person` and merge them somehow or is there a better way?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long personId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person1")
    private List<Friendship> friendships1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person2")
    private List<Friendship> friendships2;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Friendship {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person1;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person2;

    private Date metOn;

    private String relationshipType;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, and which one you choose will probably have something to do with you how you want to update the relationships.

You're going to have a table PERSON and another one called FRIENDSHIP. The FRIENDSHIP table will have two columns identifying the two people involved. The problem, in a nutshell, is that if you have the values X,Y in the FRIENDSHIP table, that also implies Y,X.

One strategy is to only store one of the two rows in FRIENDSHIP and define a rule for determining which one it is. The rule might be, X always has to be less than Y, so in order to establish a friendship between person 1 and person 2, you'd always store 1,2 and never 2,1. You can then either define two collections, or create a view on top of FRIENDSHIP that looks something like SELECT P1,P2 FROM FRIENDSHIP UNION SELECT P2,P1 FROM FRIENDSHIP and have a single collection referencing that.

The other strategy is to just store X,Y and Y,X in the table and use a trigger to add the second one when Hibernate inserts the first. In that case you can just have a single collection referencing one of the two columns, let Hibernate update it, and trust that the database will fix things so that the collection looks correct from the other person's point of view.